# Calling a stored procedure dynamically

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm wondering what the syntax is to dynamically decide which stored procedure to call.

Here's my stored procedure :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "CalculateTotalPoints"(
  "@player_id" UUID
)
RETURNS FLOAT AS
$func$
DECLARE "@total" FLOAT;
BEGIN
  SELECT
    SUM(
      (CASE WHEN p.league = 'MLB' THEN
         SELECT * FROM "CalculateMLBPoints"(s.stats, p.position)
       WHEN p.league = 'NBA' THEN
         SELECT * FROM "CalculateNBAPoints"(s.stats, p.position)   
      ) * (DATE_PART('day', NOW() - m.scheduled) < 10 THEN 1) INTO "@total"
  FROM
    leagueplayers AS p
  LEFT JOIN
    playermatchstats AS s ON
      s.player = p.id
  WHERE
    p.id = "@player_id";
  RETURN "@total";
END;
$func$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Basically the switch case determines which league the player is then uses the necessary stored procedure to calculate the value.

The other option I was thinking, to make this even more flexible is to somehow dynamically define the stored procedure name to be used by concatenating the league name ie:

```
SELECT * FROM "Calculate" || player.league || "Points"(s.stats, p.position)
```

Not sure if this is possible though.

Comment: Create single function with additional parameter `league`.

Comment: True I could do that as a backup. Just wondering if this is possible :p

Comment: It is possible to build dynamically and execute whole query (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) but not just part of it.